# line height and font size

Tags: css

What sets the height of the textbox, line height or font size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None

its

```
height
```

attribute

```
<input type="text" class="hei" id="txt1" />
<style>
.hei
{
   height: 40px;
}
</style>
```

**[font-size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530759%28VS.85%29.aspx)**: Sets or retrieves a value that indicates the font size used for text in the object.

**[line-height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530784%28VS.85%29.aspx)**: Sets or retrieves the distance between lines in the object

Answer (score 0):

```
input {
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the css option height?

Answer (score 0):

If it's `<input type="text" />` then it's a combination of `font-size`, `line-height` and any explicitly declared `height` attributes.

For `<textarea>` it's an explicit height declaration, though I think it's expressed as `rows` rather than `height`.

Comment: <textarea rows="20" style="height:300px"> will result in a 300 pixel high box. Rows get overriden by CSS.

Comment: Guess I should've experimented to work that out, huh? Thanks, enkrs, live and learn... =)